# Laravel TokenMismatch for one user only, possible reasons

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1, csrf, bugsnag

Bugsnag has been reporting a single client (same ip address) keeps receiving a TokenMismatchException throughout the last few weeks on my production Laravel 5.1 environment, no other client has experienced this issue so far.

**Stacktrace**

[image: The exception trace]

**Request Data** (Obscured)

[image: Request data]

I considered perhaps the session was dying for this particular client, that they spent too long idle on the login page however I noticed sometimes they make 2 or 3 attempts in quick succession.

I'm preparing to contact the email address but wish to understand the possibilities of why this exception keeps occurring other than a genuine attack before I do.

Comment: Do you mean user or client, i.e. do you also get the exception when you try to login with those user credentials in your own environment?

Comment: I mean to say client attempting to login with a valid email address. I don't keep production data on any local machine as a policy I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe after first form sending user got the error and then pressed F5 and confirmed `Form Resubmission` several times:)

Comment: Good point @yrv16, aside from verbose logging or directly contacting the user, I'm not sure what else could be causing their issue (If it even is an issue, the owner of the email address has not reported any issue for 3 weeks of this happening).